# Array and curve modifiers wont follow path correctly and also gets warped

Tags: modifiers, path

I am making a model of a city, and in the process of making the roads, I stumbled upon the Array + Curve modifiers not working in order to make a road profile follow the Bezier curves I have created to map where the roads go.

I have tried everything I could find online, from applying the scale and rotation, to aligning the origins of the profile and the path, and also checking the radius value of the curve (as I found online those were of the common causes of error.)

Do you have any idea what it could be? As you can see, I have mapped out plenty of curves and tried with different ones but I am still getting the same kind of error.

Here is my blender file: [download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U5YOJk--Sp46Cumli2um6n9Vv5FstoTN/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first problem is, that your plane has a z-rotation -> change that to 0.

[image]

After changing that to 0, you will see, that your curve modifier has the wrong axis:

[image]

change that to y.

[image]

now you get:

[image]

now choose your plane, go to edit mode, press R Y 90 -> and you will get:

[image]